# Why does Edit & Continue stop working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, edit-and-continue

I have a large C++ project under VS2008, and use edit & continue quite a bit during debugging.  However, sometimes after quite minor changes edit and continue simply stops working.  Debug / apply code changes is greyed out.  If I rebuild all, it tends to come back, but this takes ~30mins.  It seems very sporadic, much more so than in previous versions of Visual Studio.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

FWIW, I'm on VS2008 SP1, with Whole Tomato plugin, running on a 32bit 2G XP box.  I suspect the problem could be resource related, but this is no more than a hunch based on the fact that the problem seems to occur more often if I have not rebooted recently.

Comment: Are you hitting any of the corner cases ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dbey757(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Nope, it doesn't appear to be dependent on the type of change, it just stops working altogether, and then comes back again at some stage later.  After a corner case, a regular build (as opposed to full rebuild), gets things going again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually moved onto VS2010, SP1, and I'm delighted to note that edit and continue works like a charm.  Far better in my case than any previous versions and quite a bit faster.  FWIW, I've also moved onto a 64bit Windows 7 box with 16gb of RAM, so can't say definitively whether the problem was resource / compiler or platform related, just that the combination I'm currently using works very well.